# Android : Getting CURRENT coordinates (not lastKnownLocation)

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

Right now, I only know of one method to do this: 
- Get last known location
- Have the location manager request location updates

However, I really only need to get the CURRENT coordinates ONCE right when the application is called, but it's not doing what I want. 
What's the simplest way to get the current coordinates? Is there something I could call or some code I could use just to get the location RIGHT NOW ?

thanks in advance! I'm still a little new with android development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the simplest way to get the current coordinates?

There is no way to get the current coordinates on demand.

> Is there something I could call or some code I could use just to get the location RIGHT NOW ?

No, for three related reasons:

1. Not all location technologies are low power. GPS, for example, is a serious battery hog. Hence, GPS is not powered on unless something is actively seeking a GPS fix.
2. Not all location technologies are instantaneous. GPS, for example, takes some number of seconds to get a fix after being powered on.
3. No location technology is universally available. GPS, for example, may be unavailable because you are in a large building.